# MySQL Connector .NET EF6 operator LIKE not working

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

I am using MySQL Connector .NET with EntityFramework 6, version 6.9.5.0.

I build a query with a "LIKE" like this :

```
        var q = from u in ctx.Db.users
                where u.name.StartsWith(query)
                select u;
```

It is compiled to this :

```
SELECT
...
FROM `user` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`name` LIKE 'p__linq__0%'
```

So my query fails, because my users' name will never be like this... (maybe one day ?)

Is it a bug, an expected behavior or do I have missed something ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it `LIKE 'p__linq__0%'` or `LIKE '@p__linq__0%'`?

Comment: What's inside `query`?

Comment: Any string a user can type to search an other user. If you look at my second message, you will see that it is a known bug in mysql connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found two tickets in MySQL Bugtracker :

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74904
- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74943

Comment: These bugs have been fixed in release 6.9.6. I can confirm the fix works for .Contains() queries in LINQ to SQL / entity framework 6.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code

```
        var q = from u in ctx.Db.users
                where u.name.StartsWith(query.Trim())
                select u;
```

it works fine

Comment: It works, but it is not a long-term solution... And I can't search LIKE '% %' (contains space)...

Comment: You can use `query.Substring(0)`. Works for me.